# How to turn this into a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

```
joe 10 15 20 30 40
bill 23 16 19 22
sue 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
grace 12 28 21 45 26 10
john 14 32 25 16 89
```

Using the text file studentdata.txt above, i wrote a program that calculates the average grade for each student, and prints out the student’s name along with their average grade. Here is my code:

```
with open('studentdata.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:

        items = line.split()

        total = 0

        grades = items[1:] 

        for grade in grades:

            total = total + int(grade)

        print (items[0], (total/(len(grades))))
```

It works but I want to make it simpler using lambda functions. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: I would forget about lambdas and just use an existing average function. The numpy package has one I think.

Comment: What is simpler about using lambda functions? Which part do you want to simplify?

Comment: I want to be able to do this on different files by just running the one lambda expression

Comment: ```How would i go about doing this?``` Write a *standard* function, get it to work then evaluate whether you really want a lambda function.

Comment: Don't use a lambda function. Lambdas are for passing functions on the fly, or when the function is so simple you just don't bother to define it.

Comment: lambdas are not for simplification. They are simply for making a function anonymous. If you don't require it to be anonymous, then use a regular function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a dictionary (using dictionary comprehension) with key: student name, and value: mean of student mark, splitting according to spaces and defining a lambda to compute the mean (passing a list comprehension of all the values to it, so it can compute `sum` and `len` on it without consuming the iterator):

```
with open(".txt") as f:
    data = [{item.partition(" ")[0]:(lambda x:sum(x)/len(x))([int(x) for x in item.split()[1:]])} for item in f]
```

result:

```
[{'joe': 23.0}, {'bill': 20.0}, {'sue': 16.166666666666668}, {'grace': 23.666666666666668}, {'john': 35.2}]
```

`str.partition` is used to return the name (splits according to first space character).

So that's a one-liner including: list comprehension, dict comprehension, and lambda. Complex, but logical and performant (the `split` part is kind of done twice though, since data is heterogenous in the line: name & marks)

Comment: This is what I would call 'Jolie laide'

Comment: I know what you mean. Sometimes one-liners 1) demand sacrifices and 2) aren't necessarily the best solution. However, one-liners with listcomps/dictcomps like this avoid a lot of stupid bugs while writing the loop because of the functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this without lambda functions:

```
# 1
for line in open('studentdata.txt'):
    items = line.split()
    grades = items[1:] 

    # 2
    total = sum(map(int, grades))

    # 3
    print (items[0], total/len(grades))
```

1. You can iterate over files line by line without this overly complex `with` syntax. You also don't need the `'r'` argument as it's the default.
2. You convert each value in `grades` to an integer and then sum them.
3. I removed some unnecessary parentheses.

---

If you have Python 3.x, you can write even nicer looking code:

```
for line in open('studentdata.txt'):
    # 1
    name, *grades = line.split()

    # 2
    total = sum(map(int, grades))
    print (name, total/len(grades))
```

1. This is just a piece of cake! You extract one value from the list returned by `line.split`, place it into `name` and *whatever that's left* - into a list `grades`.
2. You can get rid of the variable `total` and move the `sum(...)` right into the call to `print` to save a line of code, but that'd probably hurt readability, so I don't recommend this.

Comment: Concerning point 1: Does this close the file after finishing the loop?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the garbage collector does it, it's guaranteed in CPython.